# Different header on TOC and Bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have defined my custom header using the `fancyhdr` package and this is my code:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\rmfamily\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\rmfamily\thechapter\ \nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
```

And I redefine the `plain` style with this:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
}
```

But I would remove the chapter number on the header of the `TOC` and the `Bibliography`. How can I do that?

This is a `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\rmfamily\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\rmfamily\thechapter\ \nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{B}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{C}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{D}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{A}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{B}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{C}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{D}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\chapter{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum
\subsection{E}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

As you can see, on the second page in the header there is the number zero near the `Contents`.

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get help if you provide a small self contained full document that others can copy and test as is. Here we don't even know what document class you're using.

Comment: The TOC and Bibliography normally don't have chapter numbers. So how did you get them there?

Comment: @daleif I update the question. Now there is the example, sry

Comment: If you're willing to switch to a different class, then this is basically the default setup in the `memoir` class, no `fancyhdr` needed. If you load `memoir` wiith the `openany` class option it is basically like `report`

Comment: @daleif More than switch class, if It is possible introduce into `fancyhr` an exception style for `TOC` and `Bibliography`

Comment: Probably, I haven't used the standard classes or `fancyhdr` for more than a decade. The problem here is that the data written to the header by say `\tableofcontetns` does not make it unnumbered automatically (default in `memoir`). It is even the default for `report` without `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @daleif How do you suggest to do to resolve the problem? Also with the class `book` there is the problem

Comment: You have `\thechapter` in your header, which causes this. It also gives `1 Chapter 1. A` for the other chapters, which is weird: it has the chapter number twice. You should remove `\thechapter` from your header definition, and if you want the chapter number before the word 'Chapter', redefine `\chaptermark` as indicated in the `fancyhdr` documentation.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I would like to remove the chapter number **only** in the `TOC` and `bibliography`. In the other chapter the header if correct

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man I didn't even notice you had used `\thechapter` in your fancyhead definitions. As Pieter notes, it does not belong there, the chapter number (when applicable) show be added to the header via the `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these definitions:

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\rmfamily\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ \chaptername\ \thechapter. #1}{}}
```